# How to run Google Glass Project on emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, maven, google-glass

I don't have a google glass device. But I am very interested to do apps for Google Glass. I want to run a Hello World in Google Glass without the use of device.

I followed the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/glass/) for Google Glass. Then I found some sample projects of Google glass. Can Anyone tell me how to run a simple Google Glass Project on an emulator or without a device.

And can you tell, Is there any alternative way to test the Glass APK developed by us without device.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to set up Glass On mobile or an Emulator in Web. Gooogle Glass is orignally a launcher over android you need to install the apks of that launcher.

**[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2298214)** you will find the APK's  (**however Camera for Glass never worked for me.**)

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObAJ.jpg)** is an Album showing you the process (on Nexus 7)

**[And This](https://github.com/harrywye/gdkdemo)** is the set of Demo's

After all set up you have to connect the android phone and then install the apk's using adb.
e.g.

```
adb install -r com.sample.packagee
```

after that you can launch the app through voice command or if it doesnot support voice trigger then launch it like

```
adb shell am start -n com.mikedg.android.glass.launchy/.MainActivity
```

**I am writing down a wiki for the issues and the to do's [Please check it here](http://jumpstartpakistan.com/wiki/wiki/3/google-glass).**.

Answer (score 1):

There are no simulators right now available to do perform testing without the device.

First :
You can try this https://github.com/zhuowei/Xenologer and install the apk on mobile device which is more or less similar to what you are looking for.

Second : 
You can try thus but u have to build your application based on Mirror API http ://glasssim.com/ or 
https ://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground

Third to have your custom apk install : 
https ://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#installing_the_samples

To display your hello world Try second option it should work.  It will add your card in Glass Timeline.

Hope this answers your question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not an emulator for Glass at this time. Testing on Glass is an important part of a Glassware development life cycle as the user experience is completely different from what you can experience on a phone or an emulator.

Feel free to follow [issue 253 on our issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=253) for updates as the GDK evolves.