# How to run my own app

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I started GDK development, and i have written a simple and small Hello World example, i installed three required APKs on my android device

> glasshome-modded.apk
>
> glassvoice-modded.apk
>
> glasssetup-modded.apk

now i am getting glass home screen and whenever i speak ok glass getting menus like: google, take a picture, record a video,... and more

but not listing my own glassware app, when trying to install apk on device, always getting open option as disabled, why?

may i know how can i run my own app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949392/how-to-run-a-google-glass-gdk-sample-on-the-device)

You need to set up a debug configuration that will work for this. Originally this application won't start without user interaction. If you go to the debug drop-down and say configure you can have it auto start an activity of your choice. So at the top pick the project then when it asks what to do say auto launch activity with the drop-down box next to it. Use the drop-down to select the activity you want to auto-start. Then try debugging the application and it should push and start automatically on your glass.

credit goes to @w9jds

Comment: as we all know i can accept my answer after 48hours only !

Answer (score 0):

> First of all normally the modded apks are available for XE6 normally
>   in which custom voice commands were not supported.

Secondly to run your application.

> 1) If you are installing using apk check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663928/how-to-run-google-glass-project-on-emulator/20699300#20699300)
>
> 2) if you are deploying you application using using IDE you can [check
>   my related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641397/debugging-gdk-with-breakpoints/20699541#20699541)